# I clearly initialized my class, but I am getting errors saying I didn't

Tags: c++

> error1-error C2259: 'HourlyEmployee' : cannot instantiate abstract class
>   error2-object of abstract class type "HourlyEmployee" is not allowed:
>    pure virtual function "Employee::printPay" has no overrider

This error is in this part and I don't understand the problem.

```
VE.push_back(new HourlyEmployee(empID, hours, payRate));
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "hourly.h"
#include "lab7.h"
#include "salarie.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

void getInput(vector <Employee *> & VE);
void printList(const vector <Employee *> & VE);
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <Employee *> VEmp;
    getInput(VEmp);
    printList(VEmp);
    cout << "Lab 7 completed by: " << "youssef zaki " << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getInput(vector<Employee*>& VE)
{

    std::vector < HourlyEmployee > ;
        int empID,
            choice;
        double salary,
                hours,
                payRate;
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter 1 for Hourly Employee" << endl;
            cout << "Enter 2 for Salaried Employee" << endl;
            cout << "Enter 3 to stop:  ";

            cin >> choice;
            cout << endl;

            // process option
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Enter the ID: ";
                cin >> empID;
                cout << "Enter the number of hours worked: ";
                cin >> hours;
                cout << "Enter the pay rate: ";
                cin >> payRate;         
                VE.push_back(new HourlyEmployee(empID, hours, payRate));
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Enter the ID: ";
                cin >> empID;
                cout << "Enter the salary: ";
                cin >> salary;
                VE.push_back(new SalariedEmployee(empID, salary));
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error: invalid option" << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        } while (choice != 3);

}

void printList(const vector<Employee*>& VE )
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != VE.size(); ++i)
    {
        VE[i]->printPay();
    }
}
```

employ.h file:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    int EmpID;
public:
    Employee(int);
    ~Employee();
    int getEmpID() const;
    virtual void printPay()=0;
};

#endif
```

employ.cpp:

```
#include "lab7.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

Employee::Employee(int empID)
{
    EmpID = empID;
}
Employee::~Employee()
{
}
int Employee::getEmpID() const
{
    return EmpID;
}
```

employsalarie.h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class SalariedEmployee: public Employee
{
private:
    double salary;

public:
    SalariedEmployee(int, double);
    ~SalariedEmployee();
    double getSalary() const;
    void printPay();
};
#endif
```

employsalry.cpp:

```
#include "salarie.h"
#include <vector>

SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(int empID, double salary) : `         `   Employee(empID)
{
    salary = salary;
}

SalariedEmployee::~SalariedEmployee()
{
}

double SalariedEmployee::getSalary() const
{
    return salary;
}

void SalariedEmployee::printPay()
{
    double weeklyPay = salary / 52;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The pay for the salaried employee with ID number ";
    cout << getEmpID() << " is  $" << weeklyPay << endl;
}
```

hourlyemploy.h:

```
#ifndef HOURLYEMPLOYEE_H
#define HOURLYEMPLOYEE_H

#include "lab7.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class HourlyEmployee : public Employee
{
private:
    double hours;
    double payRate;

public:
    HourlyEmployee(int, double, double);
    ~HourlyEmployee();
    double getHours() const;
    double getPayRate() const;
    void printPay(double);
};
#endif
```

hourlyemploy.cpp:

```
#include "hourly.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
HourlyEmployee::HourlyEmployee(int empID, double hours, double payRate)
    : Employee(empID)
{
    this->hours = hours;
    this->payRate = payRate;
}
HourlyEmployee::~HourlyEmployee()
{
}
double HourlyEmployee::getHours() const
{
    return hours;
}
double HourlyEmployee::getPayRate() const
{
    return payRate;
}
void HourlyEmployee::printPay(double)
{
    double weeklyPay = hours * payRate;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The pay for the hourly employee with ID number ";
    cout << getEmpID() << " is  $" << weeklyPay << endl;
}
```

Comment: `cannot instantiate abstract class` seems clear enough...

Comment: That error message literally does everything but actually fix the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message gives you all  the information:

> error1-error C2259: 'HourlyEmployee' : cannot instantiate abstract class error2-object of abstract class type "HourlyEmployee" is not allowed:
>   pure virtual function "Employee::printPay" has no overrider

In HourlyEmployee class you have not overriden `void printPay()`, you only added method of the same name but different argument list: `void printPay(double);`.

I suggest to use `override` keyword when overriding virtual methods:

```
void printPay(double) override; // this will generate error (signature mismatch)
```

while:

```
void printPay() override; // will work just fine
```

---

Another problem from your code:

```
SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(int empID, double salary) : `         `   Employee(empID)
{
    salary = salary;
}
```

here salary is a local variable in SalariedEmployee, to properly initialize class variable use

```
this->salary = salary;
```

---

More hints to earn extra points (From your HW) :-)

1. Do not use `using namespace std;`
2. Do not use `endl`, but instead `"\n"`
3. Do not use raw pointers, use `std::unique_ptr<>` and if you need to share it then `std::shared_ptr<>`. Those two together with `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`.

In you code you use `new` but I never found `delete` - thats asking for memory leaks.

Comment: that was really helpful thank you